# Increase read from s3 performance of lambda code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am reading a large json file from s3 bucket. The lambda gets called a few hundred times in a second. When the concurrency is high, the lambdas start timing out.

Is there a more efficient way of writing the below code, where I do not have to download the file every time from S3 or reuse the content in memory across different instances of lambda :-)

The contents of the file change only once in a week!

I cannot split the file (due to the json structure) and it has to be read at once.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket_name = get_parameter('/mys3bucketkey/')
bucket = s3.Bucket(s3_bucket_name)

try:
    bucket.download_file('myfile.json', '/tmp/' + 'myfile.json')
except:
    print("File to be read is missing.")

with open(r'/tmp/' + 'myfile.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Is this code inside or outside of the Lambda handler function? And what do you mean by "reuse the content in memory"? (because if you're re reading inside the handler I'd recommend moving it outside, but that would mean that the file contents are stored in memory)

Comment: This seems like a poor usage of Lambda.  I get that it can scale but the cost of this vs. a proper EC2 cluster has to be much higher.  The fact that the file changes once a week means it's a very good candidate for some sort of caching.  But Lambda makes it difficult to cache.  Depending on what you're doing with the data, even a smaller server should be able to keep up making a huge dent in your costs.  And that doesn't even touch the cost of reading from S3 so often.

Comment: You say "the lambdas start timing out". What timeout do you have on your Lambda function? Does it work if you increase the timeout?

Comment: I am sorry I did not publish the entire code. The code was part of the handler and was doing more that just read the file from S3. It was making external HTTP request calls based on the data on json. I realized it was bad design. I basically split the reading of the file as a separate lambda which gets invoked once and this in turn invokes (many instances of) another lambda which just makes the external HTTP calls.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you don't reach the request rate limit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html but worth trying to copy the same S3 file with another prefix.

One of possible solution is to avoid querying S3 by putting the JSON file into the function code. Additionally, you may want to add it as a Lambda layer and load from /opt from your Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html In this case you can automate the function update when the s3 file is updated by adding another lambda that will be triggered by the S3 update and call https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionCode.html

As a long-term solution, check Fargate https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/getting-started/ with which you can build a low latency container-based services and put the file into a container.

Answer (score 2):

When the Lambda function executes, it could check for the existence of the file in `/tmp/` since the container might be re-used.

- If it is *not* there, the function can download it.
- If the file *is* already there, then there is no need to download it. Just use it!

However, you'll have to figure out how to handle the weekly update. Perhaps a change of filename based on date? Or check the timestamp on the file to see whether a new one is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Place the code to get the file outside the handler function and if the last function invocation is less than x return the last result.

X is whatever delay is acceptable but lat least should be 1 second so at most your calling s3 every second for however many 000s of requests per second are handled.

You can add an internal memory cache manager also. Or use aws caching on lambdas.

You could also use the Etag in S3 and get object head. Check every second but only replace the memory copy if the Etag is changed.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/caching-data-and-configuration-settings-with-aws-lambda-extensions/